# Why assignment of path aliases and names through `every path` fails?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

---

### `every node` test-run:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,varwidth=100mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{myCounter}

% following properly creates aliases and names in "every NODE"
\tikzset
  { every node/.style=
      { /utils/exec=\stepcounter{myCounter},
        alias=nodeAlias\the\value{myCounter},
        name=nodeName\the\value{myCounter}
      }
  }

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node{node text};
    % following references to name and alias WORK
    \path[draw](nodeAlias\the\value{myCounter}.north)--(0,-1);
    \path[draw](nodeName\the\value{myCounter}.north)--(1,-1);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

### `every path` test-run:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,varwidth=100mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{myCounter}

% "alias" generates error in every PATH (undefined control sequence)
% although "name" does not generate error in every PATH, it is useless and anything that references this name will generate error (no shape named "path#" is known, where # is counter value)
\tikzset
  { every path/.style=
      { /utils/exec=\stepcounter{myCounter},
        name=pathName\the\value{myCounter}
      }
  }

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node{node text};
    % following generates error (no shape named pathName1 is known, but it was supposed to exist)
    \path[draw](pathName\the\numexpr\value{myCounter}-1.north)--(0,-1);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In your second, i.e. nonworking, example, you assign the properties to the paths, not to the nodes. Why do you expect this to work?

Comment: You need to reference a *node* either through its name or through its alias. Paths do not have anchor points (in the sense of nodes, i.e. something like `north`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look for `/tikz/name` in the pgfmanual, then there are are four hits. The first one is on p. 129 in the context of scopes and not relevant to the discussion. The second one is on p. 150 and says

[image]

This is the key which you set in your second, nonworking example. It is *not* the key that can be found on pp. 219

[image]

which you set in your first, working example, and which you probably wanted to set in your second example as well. This is why your second example doesn't work. The latter one is however the key that is to be set if you want to refer to a *shape name* later on. The fourth hit can be found on p. 352, and is, like the first one, not relevant to this problem.

The whole discussion can be illustrated by this simple example:

```
 \documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path node[name=A] {xyz};
 % \path[name=A] node {xyz}; doesn't work
 \draw (A) -- ++ (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This example works, however if we use `\path[name=A] node {xyz};` instead of `\path node[name=A] {xyz};` it doesn't simply because then the name of the path, and not of the node, gets set to `A`. The same effect takes place in your more complex code.